# Polymer: Get element by id within a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, polymer

I have a polymer element that contains a line graph using a charting library that has a built in onclick function when I click one of the data points on the chart. I set this onclick function to call a function named generatePie().

Within generatePie(), I want to modify the local DOM by grabbing an element by ID in the typical polymer convention this.$.elementid. However, "this" now refers to the function generatePie(). Is there a workaround to this?

Answer (score 0):

Sort of a hack but...created a global variable. Set an onclick function for the whole div that the chart is rendered in. Whenever any part of the chart was clicked, the onclick function will update the global variable to to one I want.

Comment: There's a much simpler way. Use .bind(object) on the function to bind 'this' in the function to whatever you want. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do `callback = function generatePie() {...}.bind(this)` where your current context is the custom component, thereby making the 'this' inside generatePie to be the component that has the local DOM?